# What is the correct syntax for an Ormlite GROUP BY query?

Tags: sql-server, ormlite-servicestack

Using ServiceStack.OrmLite with SQL Server I am trying to achieve a GROUP BY query over a mapped entity on to a DTO object but I can't seem to get the OrmLite syntax right.

The mapped entity looks like this:

```
public class MacRequestLetter
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public Guid BatchId { get; set; }
    [PrimaryKey]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime LetterDate { get; set; }

    /*
       ... elided - more properties relevant to this entity ...
    */
}
```

If I was writing the SQL manually this is what I'd write:

```
SELECT
     BatchId
    ,COUNT(*) AS LetterCount
    ,MAX(LetterDate) AS LetterDate
FROM
    dbo.MacRequestLetter
GROUP BY
    BatchId
ORDER BY
    LetterDate DESC
```

Here is the Ormlite query that I've attempted to achieve this with:

```
return db.Select<MacLetterBatch>(
    db.From<MacRequestLetter>()
        .Select(letter => new {
            BatchId = letter.BatchId,
            LetterCount = Sql.Count("*"),
            LetterDate = Sql.Max(letter.LetterDate)
        })
        .GroupBy(letter => letter.BatchId)
        .OrderByDescending(letter => Sql.Max(letter.LetterDate))
);
```

where MacLetterBatch is a DTO with properties matching the select part of the query.

However when I run this I get a sql error with message `Column 'MacRequestLetter.LetterDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

The SQL that is sent to the server is:

```
SELECT "MacRequestLetter"."BatchId", "MacRequestLetter"."LetterDate" 
FROM "MacRequestLetter"
GROUP BY "BatchId"
ORDER BY Max("LetterDate") DESC
```

which is clearly wrong in the way pointed out by the exception.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my OrmLite code?  What code would achieve my goal?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to your problem?